# Notation in Silverman's Arithmetic of EC - ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, notation

I have a question about the notation in Silverman's Arithmetic of EC. On page 2, "Remark 1.2 Let V be an algebraic set, and consider the ideal $I(V/K)$ defined by
$$I(V/K)=\{f\in K[X]:f(P)=0\text{ for all } p\in V\}=I(V)\cap K[X].$$
Then we see that $V$ is defined over $K$ if and only if
$$I(V)=I(V/K)\overline{K}[X]."$$
What does $I(V/K)\overline{K}[X]$ mean?

Comment: It’s the ideal of $\overline{K}[X]$ generated by the elements of $I(V/K)$.

Comment: One way to arrive at a meaning comes from the common notation on modules. If $R$ is a ring,  $I\subset R$ an ideal, and $M$ an $R$-module, then
$$IM=\{\sum_{k=1}^ni_km_k\mid n\in\Bbb{N}, i_k\in I, m_k\in M\},$$ which is an $R$-submodule of $M$ (exercise). Another way is in Aphelli's comment (=the smallest ideal of a bigger ring containing an ideal of a smaller ring), and leads to the exact same description.